# Supporting async=false in Ajax.BeginForm of ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using `Ajax.BeginForm()` helper function provided by ASP.NET MVC. One functionality that is missing is the support of `async=false`. In other words, Ajax.BeginForm does the asynchronous request. But I would like to do synchronously. I know I can use jQuery ajax to do this. Another option might be to change the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` file to support this. I am wondering whether I can extend `Ajax.Beginform()` helper so that it will write `data-async = false` when renders to the view page.  Any idea about how to extend this helper?

Comment: I would strongly, strongly suggest restructuring to make async work instead of fighting it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want Ajax, why not use `Html.BeginForm` instead?  Is there a specific reason why you're using the `Ajax` helper if you don't want the functionality?

Comment: I want to update a portion of my page. But I want to do it synchronously.

Comment: If `Ajax.BeginForm` receive `PartialView` how to access new DOM objects ?